# Get second representation of graph in GraphStream

Tags: java, graph

I want to create graph which represent business interaction between people and I use GraphStream library for Java. And I write such code:

```
       EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

            System.setProperty("org.graphstream.ui.renderer", "org.graphstream.ui.j2dviewer.J2DGraphRenderer");

            Graph graph = new SingleGraph("Tutorial 1");

            String styleSheet = "node {\n"
                    + "fill-color: black;\n"
                    + "}\n"
                    + "node.marked {\n"
                    + "fill-color: red;"
                    + "size: 25px;\n"
                    + "}";

            graph.addNode("A");
            graph.addNode("B");
            graph.addNode("C");
            graph.addEdge("AB", "A", "B");
            graph.addEdge("BC", "B", "C");
            graph.addEdge("CA", "C", "A");
            graph.addAttribute("ui.stylesheet", styleSheet);
            graph.getNode("A").addAttribute("ui.label", "A Node");
            graph.getNode("A").addAttribute("ui.class", "marked");


            graph.getNode("B").addAttribute("ui.clicked", "marked");
            graph.setAutoCreate(true);


            Viewer viewer = new Viewer(graph, Viewer.ThreadingModel.GRAPH_IN_SWING_THREAD);
            View view = viewer.addDefaultView(false);/**/   // false indicates "no JFrame".
            View defaultView = viewer.getDefaultView();



            JFrame frame = new JFrame("Graph");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setSize(600, 400);
            frame.add(new JScrollPane(defaultView, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS));
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
```

When I run this program, a window is shown and I get all the vertices of the triangle in the same point.
Then, when I drag vertices of triangle I get a triangle in 3D. 
Can someone explain why I get a triangle in 3D after I drag vertices of triangle? How do I get the graph in 2D?

```
  Viewer viewer1 = graph.display();
  View view1 = viewer1.addDefaultView(false);
```

The above code works fine, but I cannot understand why it does not work in the first example
Thanks for read this post. Best wishes.

Comment: I edited the title. I think you sure meant representation?

Answer (score 0):

Just use:

```
Viewer viewer = new Viewer(graph, Viewer.ThreadingModel.GRAPH_IN_SWING_THREAD);
viewer.enableAutoLayout();
View view = viewer.addDefaultView(false);/**/   // false indicates "no JFrame".
View defaultView = viewer.getDefaultView();
```

This happens because "graph.display();" calls display(true), which triggers AutoDisplay, but when you create a new viewer it doesn't come enabled by default.